# Excel: Use 2 cells to create 1 larger cell

Tags: excel

I have 3 cells that I want to use as 1 comment line. Is there a way to combine them into 1 cell so I can write a whole sentence across?

Example:

| content | content | content |

I want to turn it into one cell without those cell separators:

| content content content |

Comment: There are some who might not think of Excel as programming ;)

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: Excel is functional programming for dummies, and a interpreter with strong macro integration.

Comment: Believe me, I don't like it either. It's beyond my choice though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Highlight the 3 cells and right click --> format cells ---> alignment tab ---> **check merge cells**.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It would have taken for ever to find this by just trying to make sense of the menus.

Comment: Note: If using a mac, select the cells by mouse click and drag, not by using the command key.

Answer (score 2):

For cells A1 and B1 use:

```
Range("A1:B1").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
```

(The trick is the last line, the rest is generated using the Macro-recording features).

Answer (score 0):

Use formula similar to this?

```
=A1 & " " & A2 & " " & A3
```

A1..A3 are the addresses of source cells, & is a text join operators and spaces are just for visual separation. You might also want to check out the CONCAT() function (actual name depends on your language).